# How do you toggle hidden divs on click with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I've been trying to toggle one hidden div at a time with the class .story-overlay on click,  similar to that of .foster-container.

I tried messing with querySelectorAll but since the div is set to display: none in CSS I can't toggle on click. Basically an overlay box is supposed to appear with a brief paragraph over an image. Is there an easier way to achieve this effect? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

JavaScript:

```
var imgzoom = document.querySelectorAll(".foster-container");
var story = document.querySelector(".story-overlay");

function fosterInfo() {
  this.classList.toggle("ToggleClass");
  story.classList.toggle("ToggleClass");
}

imgzoom.forEach(imgzoom => imgzoom.addEventListener('click', fosterInfo));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="foster-container foster-toggle" onclick="fosterInfo">
  <div class="story-overlay">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
  <img class="fosters" src="../Images/Fosters/autumn-img.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.foster-container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 4px 4px 30px 4px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.foster-toggle.ToggleClass {
  transform: scale(1.6);
  box-shadow: 0px .5px 6px #000;
}

.fosters {
  width: 100%;
}

.story-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.story-overlay.ToggleClass {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just remove `this.classList.toggle("ToggleClass");`
I am not sure, do you want something like this?

```js
var imgzoom = document.querySelectorAll(".foster-container");

var story = document.querySelector(".story-overlay");

function fosterInfo() { 
   story.classList.toggle("ToggleClass"); 
}

imgzoom.forEach(imgzoom => imgzoom.addEventListener('click', fosterInfo));
```

```css
.foster-container {
border: 1px solid green;
}
 
.ToggleClass {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="foster-container foster-toggle" onclick="fosterInfo">
       <div class="story-overlay">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
<img class="fosters" src="../Images/Fosters/autumn-img.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite. I've been trying to get the .story-overlay class to mimic that of the .foster-container class, which I managed to get working well enough, the only difference being that class is not hidden by CSS. Is there a way to toggle the .story-overlay class on click of another element?

Comment: you want toggle class only on .story-overlay, when click on .foster-container, right ?

if you create snippet I would be great.

Comment: Yeah, intention is to apply "ToggleClass" to all .story-overlay classes. CSS snippet added!